# Routes are not working in laravel 4.2

Tags: .htaccess, laravel-4, routes, laravel-routing

i'm new to laravel. In my project routes are not working properly. I had already refer many answers but nothing works. In my project my **route** is as follow

```
    Route::get('/',array('uses'=>'maincontroller@index'));
    Route::get('first',array('uses'=>'maincontroller@first'));
```

my **controller**..

```
class MainController extends BaseController
{

    public function index()
    {
        return View::make('site.index');
    }

    public function first()
    {
        return View::make('site.firstpage');
    }}
```

i kept my view files properly.
when i give

```
    localhost/gc/public/
```

it loads my index page properly. But when i gives

```
    localhost/gc/public/first
```

it doesn't works. It throw an error

```
    Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException
```

when i gives like this

```
     localhost/gc/public/index.php/first.
```

it works.. properly. But i need the proper routing.

someone said there may be problem in my .htaccess file.
my htaccess file looks like this

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

But i need to know how to solve the routing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your routes controllers names need to match the actual controller.

```
Route::get('/',array('uses'=>'MainController@index'));
Route::get('first',array('uses'=>'MainController@first'));
```

Also, if you are only need the `uses` property, then you can simply write your routes like this:

```
Route::get('/', 'MainController@index');
Route::get('first', 'MainController@first');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do following things:

1. first copy all the contents of the public directory in your root directory i.e. bring the contents of public folder 1 step up.
2. modify the contents of index.php
   From => "**require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';**"
                 "**$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/start.php';**"

To =>  "require **DIR**.'/bootstrap/autoload.php';"
         "$app = require_once **DIR**.'/bootstrap/start.php';"

and also contents of bootstrap/paths.php

From => "**'public' => __DIR__.'/../../',**"
To   => "**'public' => __DIR__.'/..',**"

3.Then finally create **.htaccess** file in your root directory and write this.

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>